# Working with time as a Grails domain class field

Tags: grails, time, grails-domain-class

I have a Grails domain class called Event. It has a `startTime` and an `endTime`. What object would these two fields be represented as? I need them to persist to the database, so keep that in mind. I don't need to do anything with a particular date, just a particular time of the day, and I'll probably need to do some time calculation (making sure endTime is after startTime and such)

So...would it be easier to use a `java.sql.Time`, something in the `groovy.time` package, Integers, or something else? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like using [JODA time plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/joda-time) for it. 
Though the standard Date object works fine if you don't have to do too much in the way of calculations.

Answer (score 1):

If the database allows to use `datetime` as the datatype for those two columns, then I would prefer [Groovy Date](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html) although you get flexibility using Joda Time plugin.

Date will be [the epoch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28long%29) and groovy date provides an easy mechanism of parsing the date/time from String. For example, if `startTime` or `endTime` is represented as a string like `13:45:32` (from view or from a REST call) representing `1:45 PM` time then this string can be easily parsed to Date as:

```
Date.parse('HH:mm:ss', '13:45:32')
//Thu Jan 01 13:45:32 EST 1970
```

Conversely, after fetching the dates from persistence layer you can compare like:

`endTime.after(startTime)`

which would ultimately compare on the time (`HH:mm:ss`) since date will always be the epoch [Jan 1, 1970] in all cases.